# What protocol should I use for LoadRunner when recording windows based desktop application

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am currently looking into Performance testing for windows based desktop application

The application is build around C++/ATL, using OLEDB to talk to the database

I believe i will require COM (or DCOM) protocol to record a script around it

I am currently using a trail version of Loadrunner  vugen 2023.0.628.0 and i do not see that protocol in the list

Using Trail and error with some of the listed protocols, it launches application but does not record the requests loading the data from database

Any hints/tricks of what protocols I should use to record/replay?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Trail edition? (Rubicon, like a Jeep?)

See Documentation, LoadRunner advanced topics, integration with Visual Studio.

Or, GUI Virtual User

Or, Citrix Virtual User

Or, Remote Desktop Virtual User

Or, {Insert one of the template types here that supports OleDB with the known database queries}